# RabbitMQ Exchanges in Microservices world

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, amqp

Are there any best practices of how to organize RabbitMQ exchanges/queues in microservices architecture?

Say I have services A, B, C, D. Service D needs to consume events from A and B, publish commands to C.

My solution - Every Service declares its exchange. ExchangeA, ExchangeB, ExchangeC, ExchangeD.

Clients can publish commands to that exchange and consume events from those exchanges. These are topic exchanges, so for command, the routing key would be ServiceA.Command.Command1, for event ServiceA.Event.Event1.

For the example I've shared:

```
ServiceD binds queue (with name ServiceD.ServiceA.Event.Queue) to ExchangeA with routing key: ServiceA.Event.#
ServiceD binds queue (with name ServiceD.ServiceB.Event.Queue) to ExchangeB with routing key: ServiceB.Event.#
ServiceD produces command to the exchange ServiceC with routing key ServiceC.Command.Command1
```

Is this the right approach? Are there some good examples I could take a look?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft example micro service project here: https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

usually one Exchange and N queues are used.

[exchange image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hoZ7.png)
[queues image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt6nW.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your Exchange should not be service based but should be associated to the transaction which requires async processing of the messages. Create the Exchanges for those transactions and create and map your publishers to those exchanges. Create consumer queues and bind the queues to the exchange.
This would be the queue from where your other service will pull the message for processing. You one service can have 1:N exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

You may have only one exchange and each services consumes from their own queues (1 queue per topic-service). All services publish to the same exchange.

Following your example:

- ServiceD binds queue (with name ServiceD.ServiceA.Event.Queue) to
  Exchange1 with routing key: ServiceA.Event.#
- ServiceD binds queue
  (with name ServiceD.ServiceB.Event.Queue) to Exchange1 with routing
  key: ServiceB.Event.#
- ServiceD produces command to the exchange Exchange1
  with routing key ServiceC.Command.Command1
- ServiceC binds queue (with name ServiceC.Commands.Queue) to
  Exchange1 with routing key: ServiceC.Command.#
- etc.

You may also have multiple exchanges, 1 exchange per object type (e.g. one exchange with the customer object events and commands, and another exchange with the order events and commands).